# Finding a genterating set for the null space of T

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not really sure what my book is talking about, they didn't talk about any of this until this practice problem.

The standard matrix of T is

\begin{array} {lcr}
 1 & -1 & 2 \\
-1 & 1 & -3 \\
 \end{array}

Reduced row

\begin{array} {lcr}
 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0& 1 \\
 \end{array}

Thus the generating set is

$x_2$ =  \begin{array} {lcr}
 1  \\
 1 &  \\
0 \\
 \end{array}

What the hell just happened? I don't follow any of this at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather do this as follows" since you're looking for the matrix's null space this is the same as thinking of the matrix as the coefficients matrix of a homogeneous linear system, and thus we reduce the matrix (as this doesn't change its null space = the solution space of the homogeneous system):

$$\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1&-1&\;\;2\\-1&\;\;1&-3\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2+R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&\;\;2\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\implies \;\text{if}\;\;\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

is a solution to the homog. system (i.e., an element of the matrix's null space),. the second line above means $\;-z=0\iff z=0\;$ , and thus the first line tells us that

$$x-y=0\iff x=y\;\;\implies\;\;\text{the solution space has dimension}\;\;1$$

and a base for it is the set

$$\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

What you did is wrong as you seem to have mixed row and column operations...

Comment: Actually my book gave that answer and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I explained in my answer why, @PaulthePirate: any vector in the null space **must** have zero $\;z$-coordinate and the first two coordinates must be equal, so the space is spanned by, among others, the set given in your book and in my answer...

Comment: I don't understand how you get x -y = 0, I don't see that anywhere.